# Junit test cases for number to word program

Tags: java, junit, tdd

```
public class NumberWords {

    public String toWords(int number) {
        String result = "";
        if (number == -1) {
            result = "Number out of range";
        }
        if (number >= 0 && number <= 999) {
            if (number == 0) {
                System.out.println("NUMBER AFTER CONVERSION:\tZERO");
            } else {
                System.out.print("NUMBER AFTER CONVERSION:\t");
                numberToWord(((number / 100) % 10), " HUNDRED");
                numberToWord((number % 100), " ");
            }
        }else if(number >= 1000){
            System.out.println("Number not in range");
        }
        if (number == 0) {
            System.exit(number);
        }

        return result.trim();
    }

    public static void numberToWord(int num, String val) {
            String ones[] = {" ", " ONE", " TWO", " THREE", " FOUR", " FIVE", " SIX", " SEVEN", " EIGHT", " NINE", " TEN", " ELEVEN", " TWELVE", " THIRTEEN", " FOURTEEN", " FIFTEEN", " SIXTEEN", " SEVENTEEN", " EIGHTEEN", " NINETEEN"
            };
            String tens[] = {" ", " ", " TWENTY", " THIRTY", " FOURTY", " FIFTY", " SIXTY", " SEVENTY", " EIGHTY", " NINETY"};
            if (num > 19) {
                System.out.print(tens[num / 10] + " " + ones[num % 10]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(ones[num]);
            }
            if (num > 0) {
                System.out.print(val);
            }
        }
}
```

---

```
public class NumberWordsApplication {

    private final NumberWords numberWords;
    private final BufferedReader reader;

    public NumberWordsApplication() {
        numberWords = new NumberWords();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    public void execute() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("\nPlease type a number between 1 and 999 OR (0 to exit) :  ");
                String value = reader.readLine();
                int number = Integer.parseInt(value);
                String toWords = numberWords.toWords(number);
            } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid number");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NumberWordsApplication().execute();
    }
}
```

This is main class for generate number to word eg 57 then output should be "Fifty Seven"

I want to generate test cases for class NumberWords i have got stuck

Develop the numbers to words application using TDD

1. Implement the main application to read numbers from the keyboard
   and print out the values
2. On the server navigate to the Numbers
   project
3. Run ant to build the project. The build will fail if the
   unit tests fail.
4. ~/ant/bin/ant dist
5. The results of the unit
   tests are in the report directory which got created  Run the
   application and try it out
6. java –j Numbers.jar

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a ([homework?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)) question about Test-Driven Development, the very first steps would be to:

1. Create a very simple test case that checks that the number 1 is mapped to "ONE"
2. Create a very simple implementation that just returns "ONE" when the input is 1.
3. Create a built script (using `ant` if you must) to run this test.

Once you have this up and running you can gradually add more test cases, until your class (which will be a simplified version of `NumberWords`) can convert any input.

To keep the application testable it is best to abstain from using `System.exit()`, and to minimize code included in a `while(true)`. This is easy to do for the given assignment.

It looks like you have tried to apply TDD in the wrong order, doing test-last instead of test-first development.